# Choose by date range always at 12:00am

Tags: wordpress, reports, date-range

Still getting used to CiviCRM in general and version 5.26.2 specifically. WordPress 5.4.2.

Entering a 'Choose By Date' range seems to always default to 12:00AM in a search.  So if I search for all contributions between, say, July 1 and July 8, I get 1 July, 12:00AM and 8 July, 12:00AM.  Which, obviously, doesn't then show anything for July 8.
Same if I look just for yesterday - would show no results because the parameters are then 8 July, 12:00AM through 8 July, 12:00AM no matter what I put in the time field.  I know I can just choose 'Yesterday' from the drop down, but it was another test of results not found from input.

No errors, just no (or incorrect) results.

I'm pretty convinced that it is some setting I am missing somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: But in 5.26.2 you can enter a 'from' or 'to' time in the search if you prefer something more specific than the default of 12:00AM.  Are you able to enter times? (to the right of the date)

Comment: Hi Andy -   Yep, did that but the results still go to 12:00am to 12:00am no matter what end time gets entered.

Comment: In which case that's a bug & you could raise an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues